# Angular 2 route resolve Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am reusing a form to both create and edit records. To edit the record, I seek to pre-load data however when I click 'edit' link the URL quickly flashes to edit

For example: `http://localhost:4200/patients/-KYDTIA-kjTQaHm8_5Yy/edit`

and then flashes back to the original state: `http://localhost:4200/patients/-KYDTIA-kjTQaHm8_5Yy` and opens an empty form on the browser.

The weird thing is that when I manually type the URL and include the `/edit` at the end the page preloads with the correct data (with some delay say 2 seconds).

I am using AngularCLI (angular 2.2.1), the backend is Firebase and browser is Chrome.

I can't figure out the following:

1. Why an empty form is showing when I have a resolve in the router config to prevent the url from opening before data is preloaded.
2. Why the resolve is not pre-loading the data.
3. Why when I manually type `/edit` at the end of the URL it works as required

[Image showing empty edit form loaded with error details in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy55x.png)

**router.config.ts**

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { PatientComponent } from './patient/patient.component';
import { PatientDetailsComponent } from './patient-details/patient-details.component';
import { NewPatientComponent } from './new-patient/new-patient.component';
import { EditPatientComponent } from './edit-patient/edit-patient.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { PatientResolver } from './shared/patient/patient.resolver';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/security/auth.guard';

export const routerConfig: Route[] = [
{
    path: 'patients',
    children:[
        {
            path: '',
            component: PatientComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        },
        {
            path: 'new',
            component: NewPatientComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        }
    ] 
},
{
    path: 'patients/:id',
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: PatientDetailsComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        },
        {
            path: 'edit',
            component: EditPatientComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            resolve: {
                patient: PatientResolver
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/patients',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/patients'
}
];
```

**patient.resolver.ts**

```
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Patient } from './patient';
import { PatientsService } from './patients.service';

@Injectable()
export class PatientResolver implements Resolve<Patient> {

constructor(private _patientsService: PatientsService){}

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<Patient> {
    return this._patientsService
        .findPatientByUrl(route.params['id'])
        .first();
}
}
```

**edit-patient.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { PatientsService } from '../shared/patient/patients.service';
import { Patient } from '../shared/patient/patient';

@Component({
selector: 'app-edit-patient',
templateUrl: './edit-patient.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./edit-patient.component.css']
})
export class EditPatientComponent implements OnInit {

patient: Patient;
msgs: any[];

constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, 
          private _location: Location,
          private _patientsService: PatientsService,
          private _router: Router) 
{
  _route.data.subscribe(data => this.patient = data['patient']);
}

ngOnInit() {}

save(editedForm) {
this._patientsService.savePatient(this.patient.$key, editedForm)
    .subscribe(
      () => {
        this.show();
      },
      err => this.showErr(err)
    );
 }

show() {
 this.msgs = [];
 this.msgs.push({severity:'success', summary:'Confirmed', detail:'Record   successfully saved'});
}

showErr(err){
 this.msgs = [];
 this.msgs.push({severity:'error', summary:'Error Message', detail:`${err}`});
}

goBack() {
 this._router.navigate(['/patients']);
}
}
```

**link to edit in patient.details.component.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-lblack" routerLink="edit">Edit</button>
```

**patient-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Patient } from '../shared/patient/patient';

@Component({
  selector: 'patient-form',
  templateUrl: './patient-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./patient-form.component.css']
})
export class PatientFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  patientForm: FormGroup;

  @Input()
  patientValue: any;

  constructor(private _fb:FormBuilder) { 
    this.patientForm = this._fb.group({
      registrationNo: ['', Validators.required],
      patientName: ['', Validators.required],
      birth_year: ['', Validators.required],
      idNo: ['', Validators.required],
      gender: ['', Validators.required],
      telNo: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      dateCreated: [new Date()],
      dateUpdated: [new Date()]
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes['patientValue']) {
      this.patientForm.patchValue(changes['patientValue'].currentValue);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  isErrorVisible(field:string, error:string) {

    return this.patientForm.controls[field].dirty
      &&this.patientForm.controls[field].errors
      &&this.patientForm.controls[field].errors[error];
  }

  reset() {
    this.patientForm.reset();
  }

  get valid() {
    return this.patientForm.valid;
  }

  get value() {
    return this.patientForm.value;
  }

}
```

**patient-form.component.html - shortened**

```
<form [formGroup]="patientForm" autocomplete="off" novalidate>

    <legend>Patient Details</legend>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="formGroupRegNo">Registration No</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control has-error" formControlName="registrationNo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="formGroupName">Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control has-error" formControlName="patientName">
          <div class="field-error-message" *ngIf="isErrorVisible('patientName', 'required')">
            This field is mandatory
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>

</form>
```

**edit-patient.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-lblack float-xs-left" (click)="goBack()">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true">
            </i> Back &amp; Cancel Changes
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-lblack float-xs-right" (click)="save(patientForm.value)" >
          Save Changes
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="card-block clearfix">
        <patient-form [patientValue]="patient" #patientForm></patient-form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi maybe this help: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15782
They say that: Now resolve(true) or resolve(false) must be specified.